# How do I sign an XML POST request with oauth?

Tags: xml, lti

I'm in the middle of creating an LTI tool and the spec docs for LTI Gradebooks say that the requests must be `"Plain Old XML" (POX) messages signed using OAuth body signing [OAuth, 10].` [LTI Gradebook docs found here](https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1/implementation-guide#toc-6)

When using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, its easy, you include `oauth_signature` as apart of the POST request data, but when its XML, I don't understand where to put the oauth_signature data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone running into the same problem, you have to put the OAuth into the header of the request using the `Authorization` header field.

For more details, check out http://docs.akana.com/cm/api_oauth/aaref/Ref_OAuth_AuthorizationHeader_10a.htm